# Autoload or File Search

Tags: php, opencart, autoloader

I'm building a fork of OpenCart that involves some very heavy rewriting of the core functionality to including dedicated themes that allow for overriding the core, similar to the Wordpress theme system.

If a given controller, model or language file exists in the theme, use that, if not, use the core file.

I'm currently autoloading all the system files which works great. But I'm wondering if it would be better to also autoload all my controller, model, and language files as well?

I've noticed that (even in OpenCart) the same file gets searched via the file system, and loaded multiple times. (models and languages in particular)

Would it not be more efficient to autoload all these files then simply instantiate the exiting class, over searching for the files each time then using an include?

Let me give an example ...

My homepage contains the following modules:

Slideshow, 
Latest Products, 
Featured Products, 
Carousel

This along with the header and footer controllers ends up calling:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

23 times.

That's 23 times that the same exact file is being searched for using the file system.  Plus of course all the other models being called.

So I guess the question is really more about overhead ...

Is it more expensive to autoload (and cache) all files regardless of whether they're being called, or search the file system and do includes for each file as it's needed?

I'm sure this is an age old question but I've yet to see a definitive answer.

And BTW either answer is fine, I'd just like to be as efficient as possible in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I get Your point but to be honest You should be concerned about this only in the case You can prove that the response times are somehow slower because of this reason. After having such proof (which is relative to the server's hardware, connection speed, whether it is sunny or stormy weather or day or night) You can issue a bug and a patch-fix using the github repository.

Now the model loading performs `file_exists` check, then `include_once` and afterwards it instantiates a new model object while setting (or *replacing*) it as some key in the *registry*. Current code looks like this (`system/engine/loader.php`):

```php
public function model($model) {
    $file  = DIR_APPLICATION . 'model/' . $model . '.php';
    $class = 'Model' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $model);

    if (file_exists($file)) { 
        include_once($file);

        $this->registry->set('model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model), new $class($this->registry));
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not load model ' . $model . '!');
        exit();                 
    }
}
```

By just slight modification we can improve this code to perform only one `file_exists` check, only one `include_once` and having only one model's object:

```php
public function model($model) {
    $key = 'model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model);
    if (!$this->registry->has($key)) {
        $file  = DIR_APPLICATION . 'model/' . $model . '.php';
        $class = 'Model' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $model);

        if (file_exists($file)) { 
            include_once($file);

            $this->registry->set($key, new $class($this->registry));
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not load model ' . $model . '!');
            exit();                 
        }
    }
}
```

You can now put some time debugging into the original code and to the *fixed* one and find out whether this brings so great improvement :-)

Edit: Either way I would check how is this handled and done in OpenCart 2.0 (in it's latest status since it is not release-ready so far) and file an issue only if this is done the same way. Otherwise just fix your own installation(s)...

Comment: The engine and quite a few libraries are completely different in 2.0.  I've rebuilt this system from scratch using the 2.0 engine and libraries and the 1.5.6.1 code (removing all openbay nonsense).  What I'm building is most certainly NOT OpenCart, just based on that framework.  Thanks for your answer, this still doesn't resolve the autoloading question though, but it's a good technique.

Comment: I think that information provided in the comment should be contained in the original question (this OC 2.0 thing), I could save more than 40 minutes of my time then... Thanks!

Comment: The model method in the loader file remains the same between 1.5.6 and 2.0. You wrote 2 lines of code ... not sure why that took 40 minutes ... but ok.  Anyway thanks for your answer, it's definitely improved the efficiency. I'll mark it solved even though I still didn't get an answer to the original question.

Comment: No need to accept the answer when it really does not answer your question. I know there is OC 2.0 available on the Github but since it is being developed for maybe two years now and still not even in RC I do not need to waste my time looking at the code that may change tomorrow. Therefore I do not know how the files/classes loading is done in current 2.0 and I am really not even interested in it until it will be published. I didn't even take care of how is this done before You asked this question therefore I needed some time to think about it and to wonder about how stupid solution they use...

Comment: Yeah this is the main reason I'm building this, for developers who build solutions for their clients. It's built to be much more developer friendly.  The main purpose of any MVC framework is to prevent re-writing the same code over and over, which OC fails at miserably. I've already reduced thousands of lines of code. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Is/Will be this build of Yours available somewhere? I wanted to port OC under ZF2 with many improvements but I just have no time for this :-( ...

Comment: True, true. But you still won't be able to test all extensions on all templates and this is the point where 80% of crashes happens. Developers create extensions for the default theme while you can see some shoppica and themeforest templates (completely changing the HTML markup thus making vQmod to fail) more then often... You still won't be able to prevent the user from changing some core code and again making some other extensions not to work. Let me know when your work will be publicly accessible ;-)

Comment: Right. But like I said, this is designed for developers who know what they're doing. And 3rd party modules and widgets are implemented inside a given theme, NOT part of the core. So for instance, if you create a new theme called FooBar, you'll be able to create your own controllers, models, and language files for FooBar. These override the core files.  So any 3rd modules are implemented in the theme, not the core.  While this does require more work on the part of the dev, it keeps the system clean and free of sub-standard code.

Comment: Also just to add on, the entire system is built at the core with Bootstrap 3, so new themes being submitted will need to be correctly coded on this standard to be approved. This makes implementing changes for developers a much simpler task as the HTML5 has a given framework as well. In theory one would be able to change the entire look and feel of the site with a single CSS file.